# scrolling a particular scrollbar of DIV element

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a div element with scrollbar, i only wants to scroll this scrollbar on some event either at Top or to Bottom

```
<div id="scroll_box" style="height:300px; overflow:auto;">
 <pre>
  Top
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  Bottom
 </pre>
</div>
<button id="go_top">Top</button>
<button id="go_bottom">Bottom</button>
```

i dont want main scrollbar (windows) to move
i tried

```
$('#scroll_box').animate({scrollTop: $("#scroll_box").offset().top},"fast");
$('#scroll_box').animate({scrollBottom: $("#scroll_box").offset().bottom},"fast");
```

i m beginner, i first searched here then guess the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using incorrect values for the `scrollTop`, and `scrollBottom` doesn't exist. Also, you need to attach those statements to the `click` event of each button, otherwise they both run on load and cancel each other out. Try this:

```
$('#go_top').click(function() {
    $('#scroll_box').animate({scrollTop: 0 },"fast");
});
$('#go_bottom').click(function() {
    $('#scroll_box').animate({scrollTop: $("#scroll_box pre").height() },"fast");
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3NjDP/)

Comment: oh thanks , but i just used `<pre>` to show contents is lengthy, but actually there is no `<pre>` , so how can i reach the bottom ?? then would it be `$('#scroll_box').animate({scrollTop: $("#scroll_box").height() },"fast");`

Comment: Wrap the contents of the scrollable element inside a div, and use that. You need to have a single element which contains all content so that you can get its height for scrolling to the bottom.